# Functions are not valid as a React child -----> from a React-Native Noobie

Tags: react-native

I have gotten to grips with React, but have just started a React-Native project today for the first time. My code is very simple at the moment, but I can't seem to get it to work. I get the following error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.%s, 
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at App.js:10)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:20)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:19)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:35)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34)
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
- node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:26:24 in error
- ... 24 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Here is my code:

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Profile from './Profile/Profile.js';


export default function App() {
  return (

    <React.Fragment>
    <View>{Profile}</View>
    </React.Fragment>

  );

}
```

profile.js

```
import React from 'react';


const Profile = (props) =>{

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
        },
      });

      //style={this.styles.container}

return(
    <React.Fragment>
    <View>
    <Text>Hi Guys</Text>
    </View>
    </React.Fragment>
);


}

export default Profile;
```

I have tried removing React Fragment in case it isn't supported in React Native, but this didn't do the trick. Any suggestions?

Also on a side note, what is the best way to a debug React-Native project? This error description doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Profile` Component incorrectly.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Profile from './Profile/Profile.js';

export default function App() {
  return (

    <React.Fragment>
       <View>
         <Profile/>  // <---- The correct way
       </View>  
    </React.Fragment>

  );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Profile is a component you created and component are used by other component with the JSX syntax, like this: `<MyComponent prop1={someValueHere} prop2={somethingElse} />`.

So your use of Profile is incorrect, you should write: 
`<View><Profile /></View>`
instead of 
`<View>{Profile}</View>`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Profile component in a wrong way.

Please remove `{Profile}` and change to `<Profile/>`